# Asking without spicy / i-adjective

Tags: grammar

When I order something in a restaurant, I'd like to ask without spicy.

- I hear I have to use : `辛【から】いのぬきで` or `辛いのなしで`.
- Why `辛くないで` is not correct?

Thank you !

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This で is a method/means/condition marker, and it requires a *noun* before it. -抜き and -無し are suffixes that produce *nouns* which also work as no-adjectives. For details, see: [What does 「なし」in 「問題なし」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17896/5010)

Grammatically, 辛くない is not a noun phrase. It either modifies a following noun (eg 辛くない料理), or forms a predicate at the end of a sentence/clause (eg この料理は辛い。).

The easiest fix is to add the pronoun の ("one") after 辛くない.

> 辛くないので。

Comment: Thank you but why Japanese native speakers tell me the use of `辛くないで` is wrong ?

Comment: As I said, that's because 辛くない is not a noun but an adjective, which never directly connects to で. You have to say 辛くないので instead.

Comment: How is 辛くない any grammatically different from e.g. 行かない (which can perfectly well connect to で, as in the song title)?

Answer (score 2):

I don't think it's incorrect. Whoever serving you would still get your message and understand you. If you wanto say `辛くないで`,

`辛くない，で`　or `辛くないので` is more accurate.