# Confused by a sentence with double negation なしじゃん！(reaction of MC's little cousin after being punched by him (●｀・ω・)=Ｏ)｀-д゜)

Tags: grammar, meaning, reading-comprehension, japanese-to-english

**Hope someone can help me with the meaning of this sentence.**

**しかもグーでとか手加減なしじゃん！！！ (my guess : "Also you're not going easy on me at all with that punch/ You punched me too hard !!!" )**

**Context: MC is talking with his cousin, and she introduced her classmate and also her best friend to him. Then MC punched her (lol) for being impolite with her friend.**

Kotori (MC's Cousin)「あたしのマブ。チワプー。可愛いでしょ？」

MC「チワプー？」

Chiwa「はい。私、天枝千羽って言います」

Kotori「そッ。千羽だから『チワプー』。髪が揺れると、トイプードルの耳みたいで可愛いの」

MC「天枝さん。ムカついてたら殴っていいよ？　グーで」

**Kotori「だからマブだって言ってんじゃん！！　しかもグーでとか手加減なしじゃん！！！」**

Chiwa「あはは……大丈夫ですよ。みんなからそう呼ばれてますから」

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Usage of ～じゃん (～じゃない)](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/1481/usage-of-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%82%93-%ef%bd%9e%e3%81%98%e3%82%83%e3%81%aa%e3%81%84)

Comment: This is not relevant to your question but the MC didn't actually punch her. He told her friend she could punch her.

Comment: Kotori calls Chiwa "Chiwa poo" as if Chiwa was a toy poodle.  MC told Chiwa "Ms. 天枝, you can punch Kotori with the fist if you are offended."  Then Kotori said "I'm saying we are best friends. Moreover, you dare to say with the fist --  that's without holding back".  Chiwa is sweet "ahaha...it's alright.  Everybody calls me so"

Answer (score 4):

- グー: "(closed) fist" (*rock* as in the *rock-paper-scissors* game)
- 手加減なし: "no holding back", "pulls no punches", "merciless". なし is a kind of suffix. See: [What does 「なし」in 「問題なし」 mean?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/q/17896/5010)
- ～じゃん: "huh?", "you know?", "isn't it?"

> しかもグーでとか手加減なしじゃん！！！
> And (hitting) with a fist? That's too merciless, isn't it!?

To understand this, you need to know that a [typical *tsukkomi* gesture](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2021/07/tsukkomi-gesture.html) is done with an open hand. MC jokingly suggested グーで殴っていい ("You can punch Kotori with a closed fist"), which is too merciless (手加減なし) as a *tsukkomi*, so Kotori pointed this out.